# Regex to delete all caps letters and following comma

Tags: regex, openrefine

I have a csv of names like so `Smith, SMITH, John, JOHN` and I'm trying to use regex in OpenRefine to remove the names in all caps.

`replace(value, /^[A-Z]$/, '')` does nothing and `replace(value, /[A-Z]/, '')` gets rid of all names with any capital letters and leaves a trail of stray commas.

I need to delete the all caps names and any commas that may follow as well. I'm not interested in preserving the list by making all names lower case or capitalizing the first letter of each name. Any name in all caps must be deleted.

Comment: can you include a sample of some data?

Comment: @VishalSingh just did thanks

Comment: That regex doesn't find anything

Comment: Try: `replace(value, /[A-Z]+(,|$)/, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
replace(value, /, *[A-Z]+\b/, '')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hvdPsa/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```